# Exporting brush libraries in CC 2014

Tags: export, creative-cloud

I'm trying to export my custom brush library in Illustrator from one device on CC to another in a remote location.   This seems to depend on having your brush library appear in the libraries panel, but mine doesn't.

Has anyone done this successfully?  I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

+Finn Bartel, yes it is very Possible. This is how I do it on A PC in two steps.

**Saving the Library:**

- Create your custom brush and, from the bottom left corner of the library panel is a library icon, click on it to open a contextual menu that displays a list of brushes. But you realize the first option is Save Brush.
- On clicking **SaveAs** prompts you to save to the *temporary/roaming* location where illustrator keeps it data

> C:\Users\YourLoginAccountName\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator
>   17 Settings\en_US\x64\Brushes

- I advise you to save it in some project workspace folder say **Project X Brushes**.
- Copy that file using your explorer,  navigate to the brushes preset folder and paste it there, *mine is at..*

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC (64
>   Bit)\Presets\en_US\Brushes

Where **C** is the installation drive. Note that you sometimes need administrator privileges to save under **C:\Program Files.**
That way your custom brush will show up in the Library. **Also Note** (You can group many libraries in a folder too within the Brushes folder)

---

**Transferring the Library to the remote device:**

- Just copy this file to the equivalent location on that remote computer

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC (64
>   Bit)\Presets\en_US\Brushes